# How to make ExampleMatcher to not match the property?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to create an `ExampleMatcher` that Should not match a property. FOr Ex:

```
parentExampleMatcher = ExampleMatcher.matching()
                    .withMatcher("uniqueId", ExampleMatcher.GenericPropertyMatchers.exact())
                    .withMatcher("nodeName", ExampleMatcher.GenericPropertyMatchers.??)
                    .withIgnorePaths("id");
parent = new NetmapNodeParentEntity();
            parent.setUniqueId(uniqueId);
            parent.setNodeName(requestParamMap.get(MFTConstants.PRETTY_NODE_NAME).toString());

Example<NetmapNodeParentEntity> exampleParent = Example.of(parent, parentExampleMatcher);
```

What should I replace `ExampleMatcher.GenericPropertyMatchers.??` with so that I get the result that matches uniqueId and should not match nodeName.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure an using _not_ in an _example_ matcher fits in conceptually. However, you might be able to use a regex matcher along with some lookaround magic.

Comment: are you using this exampleParent to get data from some db later ?

Comment: Yes.. I would pass it into a JPA query